# Joining on a group by

Tags: sql

Lets say that I have three tables, customers, orders and orderDetails.

I'm doing this:

```
SELECT orders.ordersId, sum(orderDetails.total)
FROM orders
LEFT OUTER JOIN orderDetails ON orders.ordersId = orderDetails.ordersId 
GROUP BY orders.ordersId
```

But lets say the orders table contains customersId. How do I join on the customers table so that I can also add the customer's name to the fields selected?

Thanks,

Barry

Comment: Use a LEFT OUTER JOIN on table customers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it this way, which will let you get more than customer name if needed:

```
SELECT o.ordersId, o.orderTotal, c.customername, c.(other customer data)
FROM 
(
    SELECT orders.ordersId
            , sum(orderDetails.total) as orderTotal
            , orders.customersid
    FROM orders
    LEFT OUTER JOIN orderDetails 
            ON orders.ordersId = orderDetails.ordersId 
    GROUP BY orders.ordersId, orders.customersid
) o
LEFT JOIN customers c
    ON o.customersid = c.customersid
```

Comment: Your inner query doesn't return the field `customersid`, so it can't be referenced or joined on in the outer query.  It needs adding to both the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` of the inner query.

Comment: @Dems nice catch, thanks for pointing that out. this has been fixed.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT orders.ordersId, sum(orderDetails.total), customer.name
FROM orders
LEFT OUTER JOIN orderDetails ON orders.ordersId = orderDetails.ordersId
LEFT OUTER JOIN customer on customer.customerid = orders.customerid 
GROUP BY orders.ordersId , customer.name
```

Try that out or something similar.

Comment: This does work, and has nothing wrong with it, but it doesn't actually scale very well when returning multiple additional fields from multiple tables.  For maintainability I prefer to join on a sub-query, but I can't vote for it at the moment because the only answer like that is wrong ;)

Comment: In looking again I would have to agree with the sub query method too.  This is the simplistic answer with your current queries posted. ;)